# Redirecting Failed- get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django

I'm using haystack and whoosh for search feature in my django app. Things are working fine but I'm facing one problem which is; after searching for a keyword and it print out the results, when I click on the result(title), It won't redirect me to the page of the keyword I clicked on, it's just static. I tried adding a get_absolute_url method. Yet it's not working. What I'm I missing? I want to make get_absolute_url redirect users to the page of the keyword searched after they must have clicked on the title.

N:B Below is a form that makes user post their data and their data are filter on the same page.

Models

```
      class Meek(models.Model):
         user=models.ForeignKey(User)
         title=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
         address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         state=models.CharField(max_length=200)
         main_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
         side_view=models.ImageField(upload_to="photos",blank=True, null=True)
         pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

         def __unicode__(self):
             return self.title


         @models.permalink
         def get_absolute_url(self):
             findme_args = {
              'title': self.title,
              'address': self.address,
              'city': self.city,
              'state': self.state,
              'main_view': self.main_view,
              'side_view': self.side_view
         }
         return ('findme', (), findme_args)
```

Search/search.html

```
               {% block content %}

                 <h2>Search</h2>


               <form method="get" action=".">

                <table>
                  {{ form.as_table }}
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                 <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
               {% if query %}
                 <h3>Results</h3>
              {% for result in page.object_list %}
               <p>
                <a href= "{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}" >{{ result.object.title }}</a> 
               </p>
                 {% empty %}
                    <p>No results found.</p>
                 {% endfor %}

               {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
                     <div>
                       {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page= {{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>
               {% endif%}

               {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}</div>
               {% endif %}

                 {% else %}

                    {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}

                {% endif %}
                 </form>

               {% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
           def findme(request,title='title',address='address',city='city',state='state',main_view='main_view',side_view='side_view'):
               extra_data_context={}
                   #if there's nothing in the field do nothing.
               if request.method=="POST":
                  form=MeekForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                  if form.is_valid():
                     data=form.cleaned_data
                     newmeeks=Meek(
                         user=request.user,
                         pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                         title=data['title'],
                         main_view=request.FILES['main_view'],
                         side_view=request.FILES['side_view'],
                         address=data['address'],
                         city=data['city'],
                         state=data['state'])
                    newmeeks.save()
                extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form})
             else:
                 form = MeekForm()
                 extra_data_context.update({'MeekForm':form,'findme':True})
             extra_data_context.update({'Meeks':Meek.objects.filter(user=request.user)})
             return render_to_response('postme.html',extra_data_context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Urls

```
    #I created a urls.py file in my project app(testapp) folder
      urlpatterns = patterns('testapp.views',
         url(r'^$', findme, name='findme'),
         url(r'^find/(?P<title>\w+)/(?P<address>\w+)/(?P<city>\w+)/(?P<state>\w+)/(?P<main_view>\w+)/(?P<side_view>\w+)/$', 'findme', name='findme_search'),

      )

     #In my project(test) folder, where the main urls.py is, I include the above url.

          urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^find/$', include('testapp.urls')),
          #haystack url where you can search
               (r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),

         )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet `self.main_view` and `self.side_view` do not match `\w+` regexp. Moreover, it's images. You can't put images into URL string, you need to get some strings out of it. Or, if it is an object (saved in DB) anyway, you can just provide one argument, a primamry key of that object, to your URL.

You should also write a test for your `get_absolute_url` method. Then you'll be able to get an actual error quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Should the last line of your `get_absolute_url` be

```
         return ('findme_search', (), findme_args)
```

instead of

```
         return ('findme', (), findme_args)
```

?